# Loading DLL Error, MISSING: Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library

Tags: excel, vba

So I had this macro file that worked fine until this afternoon after another colleague of mine ran the macro.

when i opened it, it kept showing Loading DLL Error

[image]

I went into the object library, to find this:

[image]

Not exactly familiar with object library references here but are there any quick fixes to this?

I've tried unchecking the missing MS 16 word object but it just resets itself right after i click "OK"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a reference to Word 2016, but is it installed at your colleague's computer?
The quick workaround is to find a reference with a similar name further down the list. Microsoft Word 15 Object Library or similar will most likely do. If there's nothing like it, it is time to re-install Office
Changing the reference is a bit cumbersome though, as it'll stop working at yours. Then you must replace all your declarations of Word objects in your code with CreateObject(...)

Comment: oh my god. you're a lifesaver! was half contemplating to rewrite the whole sheet and code if i can't "unlock" the thing.

Answer (score 1):

When using same workbook from different Excel versions and with VBA reference to the Word application - you will get this error. 
Use late binding (CreateObject..) and no reference!

Answer (score 0):

First create the directory where the missing Word 16 object library should be. You will find the path at the bottom of the references window. It may be: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16. Then copy the library MSWORD.OLB found in Office14 to this new directory. Save, exit Excel, reopen. It should be ok: and 16 object library should have been automatically replaced by working Word 14 object library reference in references window.